# Что нужно для запуска .net core 3 WPF приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Нужно ли на компьютере пользователя иметь установленный .net framework или .net core для запуска такого приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто запуск? Устанавливаете последнюю версию SDK .net core 3.x (на сегодня это preview, поэтому, если Вы не используете VS 2019-Preview, нужно активировать в настройках VS что вы хотите использовать .net core preview SDK ).

Второй шаг - в проекте (*.csproj) укажите, что вы хотите использовать Windows Desctop SDK вместо стандартного sdk.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
...
```

Ну а дальше у Вас появляются все библиотеки для запуска. Как можно догадаться - данный проект будет работать только на windows.

Comment: Т.е., если я скину свою программку обычному юзеру, ему тоже нужно будет устанавливать SDK .Net Core 3?

Comment: @Oniel да, причем именно SDK ибо рантайм (c WPF) отдельный они почему то не сделали.